# How to enable ompi with MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, openmp, mex

I have C code using OpenMP what I want to include in MATLAB as a mex function. I have already done it and works perfectly in MATLAB R2013b under Linux. However, I recently read about [OMPi](http://paragroup.cs.uoi.gr/wpsite/software/ompi/download/) and according to [this article](http://paragroup.cs.uoi.gr/Publications/147cpc_chap2008.pdf) it beats most of the commercial compilers, mainly gcc what I currently use. Therefore, I would like make use of it. It works well for C codes, but I cannot make it work with a mex function. I tried it four ways:

1. Edited the CC='gcc' entry in the *mexopts.sh* file to CC='ompicc' and called `mex`
2. Directly called ompi as `ompicc -k -I/opt/MATLAB/R2013b/extern/include mex_sum_openmp.c`
3. Setting the verbose flag for `mex`, I obtained information about what `mex` is doing, so I tried to mimic it: `ompicc -k -I/opt/MATLAB/R2013b/extern/include -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -ansi -D_GNU_SOURCE  -fexceptions -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread  -DMX_COMPAT_32 -O -DNDEBUG mex_sum_openmp.c`
4. Since ompi is a source-to-source compiler, I compiled the *mex_sum_openmp.c* file with ompicc -k mex_sum_openmp.c to *mex_sum_openmp_ompi.c* and then called gcc on it: `gcc  -I/opt/MATLAB/R2013b/extern/include -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -ansi -D_GNU_SOURCE  -fexceptions -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread  -DMX_COMPAT_32 -O -DNDEBUG mex_sum_openmp_ompi.c` (this is what ompi does without the -k flag: first creates the source compiled file and then calls a regular compiler on it)

Either way, the result is the same, a bunch of warnings and then error messages.
Here is the original C file: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=70221693843831744745, here the source compiled file :http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=02497191022856307556 and here are the warnings and errors: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=93602974698898858427

Thanks

Comment: Yes, after setting the ompi copiler to the CC field, I updated the configuration by running `mex -setup`.

Comment: GCC is not a commercial compiler and its OpenMP implementation is not great. Why don't you benchmark the Intel OpenMP compiler first?

Comment: I know that it's the best, but our university does not have access to the Intel compiler.

Comment: Intel compiler is free to students and free to researchers working on open source projects. The academic license program was recently rebooted.

Comment: So you recommend to use the Intel compiler to get the best result instead of dealing with the ompi program? However, nested parallelism is better with ompi according to the article. Ok, I try to parallelize just the outer loop then.

Comment: Nested parallelism requires care. But my experiences with Intel 15 and 16 compilers are very good. Full disclosure: I work for Intel in research, but I compare our compilers to GCC 5.3 and Clang-OMP regularly, so my evaluation is data-driven, not marketing.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out. However, I will need to configure it for Linux, since Matlab does not officially support it.

Comment: ICC is designed to be extremely compatible with GCC on Linux, so I don't know why it shouldn't work.

Comment: "ICC is designed to be extremely compatible with GCC". They are different compilers, right? Doesn't it mean that I use **either** icc **or** gcc for compilation and linking? And the problem is that icc is not supported by MATLAB on Linux.

Comment: You can mix and match C compilers quite liberally. They will be ABI compatible. C++ is affected by lack of standard name mangling but extern"C" symbols will be fine. Intel compiler substitutes fast intrinsics for eg memcpy, so either you need to link with Intel C library or disable those substitutions (I can't remember the option off-hand). Just try using ICC and see how it goes. Best way to know is to experiment.